# Prove that a spanning tree exists for a connected graph.

Tags: graph-theory, solution-verification

In Armstrong's topology book, he asks the reader to

> *Show that in a graph there is a subgraph which is a tree and which contains all the vertices of the original.*

### My Proof

**Fact:** Every graph must contain finite number of cycles.

**Fact:** Removing an edge always decreases number of cycles.

Till the graph has a cycle, remove any arbitrary edge from the cycle. This process preserves connected-ness, since the edge was part of a cycle. Since, at every step, number of cycles decreases, this process must terminate. The final result is a connected graph without cycles which contains all vertices, which is precisely a spanning tree. QED.

Is it correct?

Comment: Sounds right to me.

Comment: Seems a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/97567/532409 maybe you can include your proof in the answers there.