# Is my proof that all trees have size $n-1$ correct?

Tags: graph-theory, trees

**Lemma** All connected graphs admit a spanning tree.

*Proof* By induction.

For step 0, choose any $u\in G$ and set $V_0 = \{u\}$ and $E_0 = \varnothing$.

For step $n+1$,

1. Order the vertices in $V_n$ as $\{v_1, v_2, \dots, v_k\}$ and set $V_{n+1} = E_{n+1} = \varnothing$ for the moment.
2. For each $j\in\{1, \dots, k\}$, there is a (possibly empty) set $\Delta_j$ of vertices that are adjacent to $v_j$ but *not* in $\bigcup_{m=1}^{n+1} V_{m}$.  Let $V_{n+1} := V_{n+1}\cup \Delta_j$ and $E_{n+1} := E_{n+1}\cup \{\{v_{j}, w\}\::\:w\in\Delta_j\}$.
3. If $V_{n+1}$ is empty, then stop: $T = T_{n}$.
4. Let $T_{n+1}=\Big(\bigcup_{m=1}^{n+1} V_{m},\;\bigcup_{m=1}^{n+1} E_{m}\Big)$, increase $n$ by 1, and repeat.

Graph $T$ is spanning because each $v\in G$ has a well-defined, finite distance from $u$ and $V_n$ is precisely the set of vertices at distance $n$ from $u$.  Suppose that $T$ is not a tree and therefore has a cycle, and take $v$ such that
$$d := d(u, v) = \min_{\gamma\in C}\max_{v\in \gamma} d(u, v),$$
$C$ the set of cycles in $T$.  Then $T_{d-1}$ is a tree, implying that a vertex appeared in $\Delta_i\cap\Delta_j$ in step $d$ with $i\neq j$, contradiction.

**Proof of theorem**
We use the lemma, which we may do without circularity since it stands without the conclusion of the theorem.  Every tree is a spanning tree of some graph $G$ (for example, the tree itself).  Let $n$ be the order of $G$ and $s_d$ be the number of vertices at distance $d\geq 1$ from $u$; then $\sum_{d\geq 1} s_d = n-1$ since all but $u$ itself are at a positive distance.  For the same reason, precisely $s_d$ edges are added to the spanning tree at each step $d\geq 1$, one for each vertex at distance $d$ from $u$.  Therefore, the tree has order $n$ (the same as that of the graph since it is a spanning tree) and size $n-1$.

CQFD

Comment: I am sorry but this is word salad....

Comment: Is your goal to prove that every tree on $n$ vertices has $n-1$ edges? What's your definition of a tree?

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest proof is as follows. Let $(T,E_T)$ be a maximal tree contained in $(G,E).$ Assume that $(T,E_T)$ is not a spanning tree. By connectedness of $(G,E)$ there exists a vertex $x_0$ not contained in $T$ and connected by an edge with a vertex $x_1$ in $T.$ Let $T_1=T\cup \{x_0\}$ and $E_{T_1}=E_T\cup\{[x_0,x_1]\}.$ Then $(T_1,E_{T_1})$ is a tree containing $(T,E_T),$ a contradiction.

Next if $n=\#T$ then $\#E_T=n-1.$ We will prove it by induction. There exists a vertex $x_0$ contained in the unique edge $[x_0,x_1]$ in $E_T.$ Removing $x_0$ and $[x_0,x_1]$ gives a tree with $n-1$ vertices. By induction hypothesis the number of edges of that tree is equal $n-2.$ Therefore the number of edges in $T$ is equal $n-1.$

There are other [proofs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97567/proving-that-each-graph-contains-a-spanning-tree)
on math.stackexchange.